# Размер файла apk слишком большой

Tags: android, c++

Скомпилировал на C++ Builder XE6 самое простое приложение под Андроид и оно получилось 4 мегабайта. Какое-то оно слишком большое. Возможно ли его уменьшить?

Comment: Как вариант, перейти на IDE, более подходящее для андроид, например, Eclipse + ADT

Comment: Также возможно билдер добавляет туда свои ресурсы и библиотеки. От этого тоже может возрасти объем. Проверьте сколько весят ваши папки с ресурсами и ассетами и сравните с apk.

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно. Скорее всего вы:

1. Собрали программу с отладочной информацией
2. Не удалили символы из выходного исполняемого файла

Для решения первой задачи, попробуйте посмотреть опции компилятора на наличие/отсутствие опций `-g и -O1`.

Для решения второй задачи, проверьте выполняете ли вы команду `strip` после линковки.

Comment: Выбираю что дебаг, что релиз конфигурацию - размер файла один и тотже. Не подскажите, где смотреть опции -g и -O1? И где смотреть выполнение команды strip после линковки?

Comment: Обычно я смотрю их в файлах с именем "Makefile", но в C++ Builder XE6, скорее всего есть специальная вкладка, которая отображает опции. Выполняется ли команда strip? Получилось ли исследовать то, что упомянул @Deadkenny в своем комментарии?